# Trying to do on React a List whos every item log on screen every second. Wrote a code, but gives an error (

Tags: reactjs, animation

I just have a list of items and want them appear on screen not at the one time, but one by one. What I was thinking is creating 2 arrays: one is empty and another with lists and throwing lists from one to another with set class animation on every item. Looks like I got it but gives error.

Another question is I don't really like my implementation, I think it is complicated. How would you do ? Thank you!

Here is a code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  let [listItems, changeListItems] = useState([]);
  let [listArr, changeListArr] = useState([
      <div className="item">1</div>,
      <div className="item">2</div>,
      <div className="item">3</div>,
      <div className="item">5</div>,
      <div className="item">4</div>,
      <div className="item">7</div>,
      <div className="item">6</div>
  ]);

  useEffect(() =>
  {
      let interval = setInterval(() => {
          if(listArr.length === 0)
              clearInterval(interval);
          changeListItems([...listItems, listArr[listArr.length - 1]]) // setting last item from array to new array
          let copyListArr = [...listArr].pop();
          changeListArr(copyListArr) // deleting last item from array
      }, 2000)
  })


  return (
    <div className="App">
      { listItems }
    </div>
  );
}
```

style.css:

```
 .item{
        animation: slide__up 1s;
}

@keyframes slide__up {
  0%{
    transform: translateY(100px);
   }
  100%{
      transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
```

here is a link for codeSand:

https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-moser-opcfe?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please refer to this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/blazing-flower-g8gli?file=/src/App.js) for a fix & improvement.

The key point is that directly calling `setInterval` in `useEffect` is problematic. [This post](https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/) has given a very straightforward explanation. In short, `useEffect` captures the state from the first render, and as we never re-apply the effect, the closure in `setInterval` always references the same state from the first render and would cause weird behavior.

And you mentioned that you want to simplify your logic. Several points that may be helpful:

1. You can use this `useInterval` hook to simplify using `setInterval` in hooks, [source](https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/#just-show-me-the-code)
2. You can only maintain an array and use `map` to render the components. Refer to the [React official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#rendering-multiple-components)

I've reflected all these points in my changes, in the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/blazing-flower-g8gli?file=/src/App.js) link.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

// source: https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/#just-show-me-the-code
function useInterval(callback, delay) {
  const savedCallback = useRef();

  // Remember the latest callback.
  useEffect(() => {
    savedCallback.current = callback;
  }, [callback]);

  // Set up the interval.
  useEffect(() => {
    function tick() {
      savedCallback.current();
    }
    if (delay !== null) {
      let id = setInterval(tick, delay);
      return () => clearInterval(id);
    }
  }, [delay]);
}

export default function App() {
  const [number, setNumber] = useState(0);
  const items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

  useInterval(
    () => {
      setNumber(number + 1);
    },
    number > items.length ? null : 2000
  ); // null means stop the interval

  const renderList = () => { // use map here to render a list
    const showingItems = items.slice(0, number);
    return showingItems
      ? showingItems.map((t) => (
          <div key={t} className="item">
            {t}
          </div>
        ))
      : null;
  };

  return <div className="App">{renderList()}</div>;
}
```